# DispatchEvent for TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

How do i convert this in javafx using TableView instead of Jtable?

```
 public static void disPatchTable(JTable tblFee, KeyEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            tblFee.dispatchEvent(evt);
}}
```

Comment: Is the table going to have `TextFields`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void disPatchTable(TableView tblFee, KeyEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getCode() == KeyCode.UP || evt.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
        Event.fireEvent(tblFee, evt);
    }
}
```

If it is a `TableCell` and an attempt to select a previous/next cell, it may be more appropriate to use [selectAboveCell()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableSelectionModel.html#selectAboveCell--), [selectBelowCell()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableSelectionModel.html#selectBelowCell--)